# DLL missing error when EXE run from command line [VS2010]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, ssh, command-prompt, system-error

So I built an SSH-connect-test console application using libssh library, and is dependent on ssh.dll.

The application works perfectly fine when run from inside VS2010, but gives "ssh.dll missing from your computer. Reinstall the program" error when the same EXE is run from the command prompt.

Any inputs as to why am I seeing this dual behaviour of the console application from inside and outside of VS2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Had to copy the dependencies (DLL) inside the /Release or /Debug folder to run the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

you should download ssh.dll by searching it in google .when the file downloads ,paste it in your application directery 
download it here
http://originaldll.com/file/rebex.net.ssh.dll/29300.html

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer little bit more to explain fellow programmers how it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I have it working when I run inside the VS2010 solution, so I already have the ssh.dll in place. The error happens when I try to run the same EXE from a command prompt, which is pointing at the /Release or /Debug folder.