# My program throws a "dll not found" exception when run from the Visual Studio 2015 debugger but not when run from cmd

Tags: visual-studio, dll, cmd, dllimport

My question is almost the opposite of this question (except I'm using VS 2015): [DLL missing error when EXE run from command line [VS2010]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889547/dll-missing-error-when-exe-run-from-command-line-vs2010)

I've developed a small program in Visual Studio 2015. When I run my program using the Visual Studio 2015 debugger, I get an error saying that  "iphlpapi.dll" wasn't found. When I open cmd and cd to the bin folder of my project and run the project's .exe from the command line, the program returns the output I expect. iphlpapi.dll does exist on my machine (in C:\Windows\System32 and a few other locations).

I've confirmed that the bitness of the executable I run is 32 in both cmd and VS. Why is the error only happening in VS? Does VS look for .dlls in a different location than a program run from cmd?

Comment: I suggest to read the Microsoft articles about [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/wow64-implementation-details) and [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector). Is there a file `iphlpapi.dll` (x86 version) existing also in directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` and not only in `%SystemRoot%\System32`(x64 version)?

Comment: Visual Studio modifies __local__ environment variable `PATH` for itself and all processes started from within Visual Studio. Is the folder path `%SystemRoot%\System32` included in environment variable `PATH` on executable started by Visual Studio debugger? Free Sysinternals [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is in general very helpful to find out why a file could not be found as expected. It makes it possible to see where an application is searching for a file and which environment variables were set with which values on starting the application.

Comment: @Mofi there is a copy of `iphlpapi.dll` in both locations. I'll have a look at your links, thanks

Comment: It is a very unusual mishap, you can't break the OS with a bad PATH.  A somewhat likely scenario is a crappy anti-malware product, they often get their underwear in a bundle when an .exe file appears from seemingly nowhere and starts doing network related things.  So temporarily disable it and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @Mofi I ran Process Monitor and compared the events for the cmd run and the VS run using this handy tool: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kenliu/2007/09/12/process-monitor-logs-analysis/. Strangely, iphlpapi.dll isn't present in the logs for either context, and when I compare operations that resulted in NAME NOT FOUND, they're identical. In general it appears the VS is loading more stuff than CMD. Very weird.

Comment: @HansPassant that's a good idea, but the machine running the programs is actually an Azure VM with no anti-malware running on it that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I was running cmd as an administrator, whereas VS was run as a normal user. Running VS as an administrator fixed the problem.